# VB.NET Cannot attach database query

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-connection

I've a problem with connection VB.NET to Sql Server 2008 databases. I've already try to create a connection string and it still cannot attach and detect database query yet. It's show an error like this [image]

This is my code I use:

```
Public Class Authentification

Private Sub Authentification_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    buka()
End Sub

Private Sub btlogin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btlogin.Click
    Dim Sql, user, pass As String
    user = txtusername.Text
    pass = txtpassword.Text
    koneksi.Close()
    Call buka()
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM tAdmin WHERE username = '" + user + "' AND password='" + pass + "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(Sql, koneksi)
    baca = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If baca.Hasrows = True Then
        MenuUtama.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Username atau password salah", "Konfirmasi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        txtusername.Focus()
    End If

    txtusername.Text = ""
    txtpassword.Text = ""
    baca.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
End Sub

End Class
```

And this is the code for module buka:

```
Module Module1

Public koneksi As SqlConnection
Public data As DataSet
Public baca As SqlDataReader
Public adaptor As SqlDataAdapter
Public cmd As SqlCommand
Public ass As DataTable
Public str, sql As String

Public Sub buka()

    str = "Data Source=DON-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbFutsal;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=******"
    koneksi = New SqlConnection(str)
    Try
        If koneksi.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            koneksi.Open()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End Try

End Sub
End Module
```

Can someone tell me what i'm wrong? Thanks before

Comment: It cannot find your datasource. `str = "Data Source=DON-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbFutsal;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=erbasganedan"` - This part is incorrect

Comment: @KayNelson can you tell me the sample?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ The code could just be fine, the error message says it cannot find the datasource. Is the service running? Also, remove the `Persist Security Info=True` or set it to false.

Comment: @KayNelson Still error like that Sir. I've check services for sql server too and it all started

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have the login user "sa" in your database. Also try removing "persist security info" from the connection string.

Comment: I have created the login user for sa, and I've try to removing "persist security info" and still error like before

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, probably not a good idea to publicly post your sa password.

But, let's keep it simple. Try this and see if it connects. if it doesn't work, please post error message.

```html
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conDB As New SqlClient.SqlConnection

        Dim strConnectionString As String = "Data Source=ServerName;" & _
                                            "Database=DatabaseName;" & _
                                            "User Id=UserName;" & _
                                            "Password=Password;" & _
                                            "Connect Timeout=90;"
        Debug.WriteLine(strConnectionString)
        conDB.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
        Try
            conDB.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        ' Do something

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if this is not the same computer with the SQL database on it, try turning firewalls off and connecting again (on both the server and your client).

Comment: I created it in the same computer, local database

Answer (score 0):

Only other thing I can suggest is to ensure you have the SQL Server Services running.

go to control Panel, Services, sort alphabetically and look for SQL Server. Start all services that aren't started already.

Comment: all sql server services started, but still the same error. But thanks you for answering Sir

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local db (like you said earlier) try `Data Source=(local);` instead of `Data Source=DON-PC\SQLEXPRESS;`